# AWS SES for bulk mail : Require email verification?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

We're thinking of moving to [Amazon's SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/?ref_=pe_8050_18775270) for sending bulk mail.  [It appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876538/amazon-ses-simple-email-service-for-bulk-e-mail-not-for-transactional-e-mails) that we have a unique API call for each email we want to send.  So if there are 20k emails to send, we make 20k API calls.  My question is, do we need to verify these email addresses before we send to them?  We have an existing database of users and I'd rather the transition to SES to be transparent to them.

I noticed that SES has an [API method](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/APIReference/index.html?API_VerifyEmailAddress.html) for verifying emails.  If we aren't required to verify, why would someone would use this method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/APIReference/index.html?API_SendRawEmail.html says:

> Important:
>   If you have not yet requested production access to Amazon SES, then you will only be able to send email to and from verified email addresses.

So, that method you asked about is used for building a list of addresses that can be e-mailed to, if you haven't requested production access yet. Since you seem to already have done that, it's not useful to you.

Comment: Thanks for the info but can you tell how do i request for production access ?

Answer (score 4):

Note - once you have production access, you will still need to verify email addresses you are sending FROM, but not to.

Comment: A side note: You'll want to because they have very strict guidelines on bounces and such.