# Does Amazon SES provide bulk email processing service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, email

Does Amazon SES provide bulk email processing service?

I tried using amazon SES for sending emails.There is sequential access for sending mails. For bulk processing in faq, they are saying to send email through multiple iterations. Is there any other way i can send bulk mails through amazon ses.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Amazon SES (Simple Email Service) for bulk e-mail, NOT for transactional e-mails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876538/amazon-ses-simple-email-service-for-bulk-e-mail-not-for-transactional-e-mails)

Comment: Have you considered sending one email with recipients as BCC? Note, however, there is a 50-recipient limit per message.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein that may mess up the bounce and complaints feedback loop, please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38722615/amazon-ses-hide-recipient-email-addresses#comment64842899_38722615)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to send emails to multiple recipients, without exposing the email addresses to each recipient, and without using BCC, then you would have to send the emails once at a time with SES. Also, if you wanted to personalize each email then you would have to send them one at a time with SES.

SES is not a bulk email service like MailChimp or SendGrid.