# Amazon SES - Hide recipient email addresses

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, boto3

I am testing Amazon SES through boto3 python library. When i send emails i see all the recipient addresses. How to hide these ToAddresses of multiple email via Amazon SES ?

[image]

Following is the part of the code

```
import boto3
client=boto3.client('ses')
to_addresses=["**@**","**@**","**@**",...]

response = client.send_email(
    Source=source_email,
    Destination={
        'ToAddresses': to_addresses
    },
    Message={
        'Subject': {
        'Data': subject,
        'Charset': encoding
        },
        'Body': {
            'Text': {
                'Data': body ,
                'Charset': encoding
            },
            'Html': {
                'Data': html_text,
                'Charset': encoding
            }
        }
    },
    ReplyToAddresses=reply_to_addresses
)
```

Comment: Send them as a BCC instead of a to?

Comment: From memory, it doesn't let you do BCC that way, you need to create a message yourself and send raw. See answer below.

Comment: SES is [billed per recipient](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/pricing/), not per mesage... so if you are sending the same message to multiple recipients for cost reasons... don't.

Comment: @michael: I think you're right! I need to do personalization as well for each emails. So, I can loop in the recipients and replace the personalization variables. Is it the best practice ?

Comment: I would say so.  It will simplify tracking deliveries, bounces, and complaints as well.  Tracking them is not impossible with multiple recipients, but it gets tricky, particularly with complaints. [It's critical](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/notifications.html) that you handle these properly and immediately stop sending to complainers ... and similarly important that you stop sending to bouncing addresses -- SES doesn't mess around when it comes to shutting down people who are careless.  The sending quota also applies against recipients, not messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use the send_raw_email function instead which gives more control over the make up of your message. You could easily add Bcc headers this way.

An example of the code that generates the message and how to send it

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = 'Testing BCC'
msg['From'] = 'no-reply@example.com'
msg['To'] = 'user@otherdomain.com'
msg['Bcc'] = 'hidden@otherdomain.com'
```

We use templating and MIMEText to add the message content (templating part not shown).

```
part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain', 'utf-8')
part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html', 'utf-8')
msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)
```

Then send using the SES send_raw_email().

```
ses_conn.send_raw_email(msg.as_string())
```